# Why do I need mod keyword for accessing structs in file at same level for Rust?

Tags: rust

```
mod pair;
mod point;
mod rectangle;

use pair::Pair;
use point::Point;
use rectangle::Rectangle;
```

Shouldn't these structs be available in the same scope for code files at same level as pair.rs, point.rs and rectangle.rs?

And is there python like syntax?

```
from A import B
```

Comment: Rust was built for security. You can only modify values of variables with that keyword I am pretty sure.

Comment: this is not about variable. but using types. is there way to reduce this to one line?

Comment: For what it's worth - Rust doesn't tend to follow the same 'one struct/class per file' idiom as languages like Java or C#. You're better off putting related functionality into one module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust's module system allows you to split code into small, reusable modules.
You declare new module using `mod` keyword. Every module has its own scope. It means that if you want to use `struct` (or anything else) from module, you need to type `module_name::StructName` or bring it into your code's scope using `use` keyword (`use module_name::StructName`). This is because there might be two different structs with the same name in two different modules. E.x. There is a struct `A` in module `b`, and there is struct `A` in module `C`. If there wasn't separate scope for each module, which struct `A` would be imported? Rust wouldn't be able to figure out what was our intention. It may cause bugs and other issues.

To import module you need to use module's name double colon and name of the imported submodule or struct e.x.

```
use std::io;
```

To import all submodules of one module you need to use module's name double colon and star sign, e.x.

```
use std::*;
```

You can also refer to parent module using `super` keyword and import all its modules at once, e.x.:

```
mod pair;
mod point;
mod rectangle;

use super::*;
```

Since [Rust 1.25](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/03/29/Rust-1.25.html) you can nest import groups, e.x.:

```
use std::{
    cmp::{self, Ordering}, 
    fs, 
    io::prelude::*,
};
```

Please also read:

- [Using Modules to Reuse and Organize Code - The Rust Programming

  Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch07-00-modules.html)
- [Using super to Access a Parent Module - The Rust Programming

  Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch07-03-importing-names-with-use.html#using-super-to-access-a-parent-module)

Comment: another thing.. can  i `use` without declaring mod?

Comment: No, you have to declare every `mod`ule of your lib/app (inside `lib.rs`). Then you can freely `use` declared modules inside other modules. When you want to use them in your app (inside `main.rs`), you have to `extern crate`. However, when you `extern` someone's `crate`, you `use` without declaring modules, because they have been already declared inside the crate (by the author of it)